# Where clause and Count together in a DB Query Laravel

Tags: laravel, count, where-clause

I have a DB Query that using SUM and COUNT, but i need to add a where clause withing the Count.

I have tried this and it is not working :

```
->select(DB::raw('SUM(value1) as value1, COUNT(value2) as value 2 where id = 1))
```

Comment: you can't `where` inside a `count()`, or any other function. you can fake it via somethign like `SUM(somefield = somevalue)`, which will add up the boolean true/false results as 1/0.

Comment: @MarcB , How would i add some form of where to the COUNT . as i have a few COUNT within this query as a whole. i just need to count value2 where value 2 is = to A for example, using the int 1 was an example.Thanks

Comment: Any luck for @Matt

Answer (score 0):

Use sum() in place of count(). Like this:

```
->select(DB::raw('SUM(value1) as value1, SUM(if('YOUR_TABLE'.id = 1, 1, 0)) AS value2)
```

Comment: sorry that did not work. i am trying to count the records in table name where there id is = to admin.